# What is the best approach to implement configuration app with Django?

Tags: python, django, configuration, django-models, django-admin

I need to program kind of configuration registry for Django-based application.

Requirements:

1. Most likely `param_name` : `param_value` structure
2. Editable via admin interface
3. Has to work with syncdb. How to deal with a situation in which other apps depend on configuration model and the model itself has not been initialized yet in DB? Let's say I would like to have configurable model fields properties, i.e. the default value setting?

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found [djblets.siteconfig](http://www.chipx86.com/blog/?p=261) very useful. Works great with the Admin app, and very easy to use. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Once a while (year ago) I used [dbsettings](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) to have some sort of business configuration accessible via admin interface, but I cann't say how it fits today.

Comment: TODO: Integration with newforms-admin :/

Thanks, it's probably worth checking out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have trouble if you make other apps depend (at interpretation/app-loading time) on values set in your config app.  Can you use some kind of placeholder value in Python code at interpretation time, and then pull in the real config data on the post_syncdb signal?